# How to isolate the "first_name" key to output its value in the following object?

Tags: javascript, object

How to isolate the `first_name` key to output its value in the following object?

```
{
    "first_name": "D",
    "last_name": "N",
    "phone_number": 1233414234
}
```

Comment: what if it is an array of objects and i want to get all the first names: var array = [{"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234},{"first_name":"P","last_name":"T","phone_number": 1233414234}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.` or `[]`

```
 var x = {"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234};
 alert(x.first_name);
 alert(x['first_name']);
```

Reference is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

**EDIT**

Based on OP question in comment in the other answer: if you want to iterate through objects of an array, you can use each.

```
var array = [{"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234},{"first_name":"P","last_name":"T","phone_number": 1233414234}];
$.each(array, function(idx) {
    alert(array[idx].first_name);
});
```

OR

```
var array = [{"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234},{"first_name":"P","last_name":"T","phone_number": 1233414234}];
$.each(array, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.first_name);
});
```

Comment: Waow! Another downvote for the first and working solution. Love it.

Comment: Can't see any reason for this to be downvoted so I've upvoted it for you

Comment: @JamesMonger Thank you, this SO is a magic place :) If downvoter just explain why did it world will be a better place :)

Answer (score 2):

Either with *dot notation* or with *bracket notation*. Read more about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var object = { first_name: "D", last_name: "N", phone_number: 1233414234 };

// dot notation
console.log(object.first_name);
 
// bracket notation
console.log(object['first_name']);
```

For an array of objects, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)-

```js
var array = [{"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234},{"first_name":"P","last_name":"T","phone_number": 1233414234}],
   first_names = array.map(function (a) {
       return a.first_name;
   });

console.log(first_names);
```

Comment: what if it is an array of objects and i want to get all the first names: var array = [{"first_name":"D","last_name":"N","phone_number": 1233414234},{"first_name":"P","last_name":"T","phone_number": 1233414234}]

Comment: @Pablo.K See my edited answer. There is the solution for you.